# Div height to be remaining space of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport, jquery-isotope

I apologize for the poor wording of my title, I am not sure how to explain my question in the most concise way.

I have an isotope JavaScript plugin that filters I use to filter some elements. The plugin works fine, however I added my own "No results" text that appears when there are no results. It functions correctly, however what is not working is the animation.

At the moment, if you are scrolled down on the page, and the results go from multiple shown results to 0 results where my "No Results" code appears, there is an animation glitch where my footer (which I have set using flex display to be at at the bottom of the screen) moves up from the bottom, and then snaps into the bottom.

I have worked out that one possible solution for this may be to give the "No results" text a height that would make all of the contents on the page add up to 100vh. Is there a way to calculate it so that it will be the calculated height of what is left on the page to ensure the min size of the contents of the page are 100vh.

Here are some screenshots of the issue:

This is how it should look the entire time when there are no results. However this only happens at the end of the animation
[image: This is how it should look the entire time when there are no results. However this only happens at the end of the animation]

This is what happens during the actual animation. The page resizes in a strange way where the footer first moves up, leaving the white space at the bottom and only then does it snap down into position.
[image: This is what happens during the actual animation. The page resizes in a strange way where the footer first moves up, leaving the white space at the bottom and only then does it snap down into position.]

Attached is the live code of my site, to see what I mean, please first scroll down and then click the "Financial Sustainability" checkbox.
[Link to live code](http://eg-graphics.com/SEIL/resources.html)

If anyone has any advice at all about this, even on how to explain the question better, I am open to any feedback and suggestions and I really appreciate all of the support.

Comment: Can you attach some screenshot, it would make it more clear.

Comment: What you have provided as *link to live code* is not code but a *live demo*, if you want anyone to help you you should be providing the code.

Comment: If you could provide screenshots and explain your problem with help of them?

Comment: @JiteshDhamaniya I have added some screenshots, apologies for not doing this immediately.

Comment: place a fixed height you want to have on that middle div (where your checkboxes are) and scale it depending on your resolution

Comment: @EugenSunic what method would you use to scale and what would the scaling factor be based on?

Comment: use     ```height: 100vh; on second row div class="row" ``` inside the container and work your way out with the scaling factor based on resolution if you want, there are a lot of possibilites here depending on your needs, as others have said we need code...

Comment: @EugenSunic can not give code unfortunately, since that whole page basically is the code :\ I can not isolate only certain parts of it, since everything needs to work together to replicate the issue.

Comment: did you try the ```height:100vh``` on that div, does that help?